# How to open secure Websocket (WSS) to Kafka websocket proxy server

Tags: ssl, websocket, apache-kafka

We have 2 Servers - One Apache Server for secure (https) upload of an html page.  (https://trial.xxx.org) Apache server running with SSL. Other is Kafka Webproxy  Server as per  (https://github.com/Microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws) using wsPort: 9999

Chrome Browser is client which uploads https://trial.xxx.org with JavaScript page with Websocket code - both of ws and wss fail:

Error: 'ws://proxyserver:9999
“Mixed Content: The page at 'https://trial.xxx.org//main_page/main.jsp?pg=PRACTITIONER' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://proxyserver:9999/?topic=16-59408-5'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.”

Error: 'wss://65.111.165.95:9999/
After change in kafka ws to wss on kafka proxy side we see error as below:
kafka.js:11 WebSocket connection to 'wss://webproxy:9999/?topic=16-59408-5' failed: **Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**
Hence both wss and ws failed. We would like to use wss.

Do we need to change the kafka websocket proxy code to support wss? Or we are missing Apache setup.

Any clues are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this instead of `Microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws` :
https://github.com/Effyis/kafka2websocket

It's pretty simple to setup and it supports `wss`.